# Windows 7 will not enter sleep or hibernate mode

Tags: windows-7, linux, drivers, sleep, hibernate

Just recently Windows 7 started refusing to enter sleep or hibernate. I have just installed Ubuntu on the same hard drive and they are dual booting just fine, usually this isn't a problem, but I don't use windows all that much so I am not too sure of what I'm doing with it, or what could be causing it. I did disable all the devices ability to wake the computer from sleep (except the mouse) via Device Manager. I also made sure hibernate was turned on and the hiberfil.sys was intact.

I checked the powerconfig requests also, it's telling me that there are no requests that interrupt the hibernation / sleep process.

```
C:\>powercfg.exe /hibernate on

C:\>powercfg.exe -h on

C:\>attrib.exe h*.*
A  SH   I    C:\hiberfil.sys

C:\>powercfg /requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
None.

AWAYMODE:
None.


C:\>
```

I also ran the energy report, which only gave me these errors, and I don't think any of these could be the problem.

```
Power Policy:Power Plan Personality is High Performance (Plugged In)
The current power plan personality is High Performance when the system is plugged in.
Power Policy:Minimum processor performance state is 100% (Plugged In)
The processor is not configured to automatically reduce power consumption based on activity.
Power Policy:PCI Express ASPM is disabled (Plugged In)
The current power policy for PCI Express Active State Power Management (ASPM) is configured to Off.
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
The USB device did not enter the Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented if a USB device does not enter the Suspend state when not in use.
Device Name USB Root Hub
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E2D
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 26, function 0
Device ID   USB\VID_8086&PID_1E2D
Port Path   
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
The USB device did not enter the Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented if a USB device does not enter the Suspend state when not in use.
Device Name USB Root Hub
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E26
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 29, function 0
Device ID   USB\VID_8086&PID_1E26
Port Path   
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
The USB device did not enter the Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented if a USB device does not enter the Suspend state when not in use.
Device Name Generic USB Hub
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E2D
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 26, function 0
Device ID   USB\VID_8087&PID_0024
Port Path   1
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
The USB device did not enter the Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented if a USB device does not enter the Suspend state when not in use.
Device Name Generic USB Hub
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E26
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 29, function 0
Device ID   USB\VID_8087&PID_0024
Port Path   1
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
The USB device did not enter the Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented if a USB device does not enter the Suspend state when not in use.
Device Name USB Input Device
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E26
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 29, function 0
Device ID   USB\VID_0A5C&PID_4503
Port Path   1,6,2
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
The USB device did not enter the Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented if a USB device does not enter the Suspend state when not in use.
Device Name USB Composite Device
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E2D
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 26, function 0
Device ID   USB\VID_1B1C&PID_1B12
Port Path   1,5
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
The USB device did not enter the Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented if a USB device does not enter the Suspend state when not in use.
Device Name Generic USB Hub
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E26
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 29, function 0
Device ID   USB\VID_0A5C&PID_4500
Port Path   1,6
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
The USB device did not enter the Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented if a USB device does not enter the Suspend state when not in use.
Device Name USB Composite Device
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E2D
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 26, function 0
Device ID   USB\VID_1B1C&PID_1B17
Port Path   1,1
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
The USB device did not enter the Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented if a USB device does not enter the Suspend state when not in use.
Device Name USB Input Device
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E26
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 29, function 0
Device ID   USB\VID_0A5C&PID_4502
Port Path   1,6,1
CPU Utilization:Processor utilization is high
The average processor utilization during the trace was high. The system will consume less power when the average processor utilization is very low. Review processor utilization for individual processes to determine which applications and services contribute the most to total processor utilization.
Average Utilization (%) 4.98
Platform Power Management Capabilities:PCI Express Active-State Power Management (ASPM) Disabled
PCI Express Active-State Power Management (ASPM) has been disabled due to a known incompatibility with the hardware in this computer.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a just a suggestion, but you could try to look in the registry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power
```

and look if `HibernateEnabled` has the `value 1`.

You should also look at `HiberFileSizePercent` and make sure that enough memory is allocated.

After changing something be sure to restart your computer.

Comment: @user3078156 what do you meant by a bad hard detail, can you give some more explanation